# Angularjs view not showing, caused by factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem adding factory functions to my AngularJs module.

When I add the '**authInterceptor**' factory function to my **home** view module. The view isn't loading. But when I delete the factory function it does load.

What am I doing wrong?

**Home controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    responseError: function (rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
})

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });

}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {
  console.log("Home Controller");


});
```

**general module loader**

```
// public/js/app.js
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.home'

])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
  function($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');



    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}])
.run(function($rootScope, $http){
  $rootScope.my_message = 'test';



});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your factory has a semi-colon, which breaks the following code.

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function () {
  return 'a12345654321x';
}); //<==== remove this semicolon

//otherwise this breaks
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
  //etc

}])
```

Edit for your second problem: You are missing the $httpProvider in your dependencies.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider

=>

.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. It was definitely the answer in my question. But I actually made my code as small as possible and I made the mistake myself. Now I reverted back my removed code and my view still disappears. Could you please take a look at the new code?

Comment: Check the edit. You are missing the $httpProvider monkey-patching